# SharePoint Document Column Options

Tags: sharepoint, document

I am trying to create columns on a shared document repository such that they 'drill down.'  For example, if you have choices A, B, and C for the first (and currently only available) column, then your choice will determine the other columns that become visible, allowing a guided addition of documents. Is this something that is possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Try [$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation). This implies that you will have to implement a custom/modified list form.